# Rails Activerecord last 5 records based on field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to fetch the last 5 records where transfer = something.  Currently I'm using: `Model.limit(5).order('id desc')` but that shows the last 5 of `Call.all`.  How can I express this by adding a where clause or specifying a particular value as part of the query?

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
Model.where(:transfer => 'something').order('id desc').limit(5)
```

But it might make more sense to order by `created_at` or `updated_at` instead of `id`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I'm using Devise and associations to say current_user has these call records based on transfer_from_id which matches a facility_id.  How could I use the above code to say where transfer_from_id = :id and :id being something passed in?  Sorry if I'm not wording it right, I'm a bit new.

Comment: I can do: @last5 = Call.where(:transfer_from_id => '1').order('id desc').limit(5) But transfer_from_id '1' matches the facility_id 1 in User.rb so I can associate properly.  What if a user has a facility id of 2?  How can I get that using your code?

Comment: What does `facility_id` have to do with `transfer_from_id`? There's nothing about that in your question. Just replace the parameters of the `where` call with the conditions you need. Given a variable `id`, `where(:transfer => id)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  The facility_id represents a facility name in a model.  I had mistyped in my comment, ignore the relations between the two, it would be too long to explain how I have the associations (and why) setup.